# Ruby Hash that's been Mashed needs to be First for Solidfist Rockgroin. What?

Tags: ruby, hash, rubygems

I was never one to question peoples lifestyle choices. Especially when *he* walked in the door. His handshake was like iron, and his request was simple enough after the ringing in my ears subsided. "**Listen user**" he barked, "**I need to be converted from XML to a pseudo-object and I need it done *YESTERDAY*!**" And with that, he swept out of my office like a tiny muscle tornado on the heels of a sonic boom.

So I got to work. First up:

```
<employeeRecord>
    <employee>
        <firstName>Crunch</firstName>
        <secondName>Crumble</secondName>
        <thirdName>Destructo</thirdName>
        <fourthName>Solidfist</fourthName>
        <lastName>Rockgroin</lastName>
    </employee>
    <dependent>
      <spouse type = "spouse">
        <firstName>Betty</firstName>
      </spouse>
      <child>
        <firstName>Timmy</firstName>
      </child>
    </dependent>
</employeeRecord>
```

Simple enough. After researching Ruby I came across a tiny gem called Hashie, and with it, I do the following:

```
class Person
  def initialize
    @xml = Mash.new(XmlToHash.getHash)
  end
  attr_accessor :xml
end
```

Wonderful! I simply need to reference my client now and as a simple test, pull up his last name. With the wonderful Mash, I can do this very easily!

```
MyClient = Person.new
MyClient.xml.employee.first.lastName # => 'Rockgroin'
```

Wait, hang on a second. What's **first** doing there? What if I got rid of it?

```
MyClient.xml.employee.lastName # => END OF THE WORLD. ABANDON YOUR IDE.
```

What? But...why? The content of the hash at .employee.first looks like this after getting Mashed:

```
 #<Hashie::Mash firstName=["Crunch"] fourthName=["Solidfist"] lastName=["Rockgroin"] secondName=["Crumble"] thirdName=["Destructo"]>
```

And if there's a first, then what is last?

```
#<Hashie::Mash firstName=["Crunch"] fourthName=["Solidfist"] lastName=["Rockgroin"] secondName=["Crumble"] thirdName=["Destructo"]>
```

The same blasted thing?! What's going on here? This code is almost as mysterious as my client. What's happening? Can some kind soul explain what in the devil is going on here, and what first/last are doing?

Comment: There could be more than one `<employee>` tag, so it assumes it's a collection. Unrelated, but in general, it's best to keep the unrelated chatter to a minimum.

Comment: XmlToHash just calls XmlSimple.xml_in(). The same effect can be had using REXML.

Comment: `XmlSimple` is parsing the elements into an array. Try adding the `:ForceArray => false` option to your call to `XmlSimple.xml_in`.

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea it was doing that as default behavior. It works exactly as expected now. How do I provide you with an upvote friend?